# My implemented merge sort not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, mergesort

I have been implementing merge sort in python without creating an extra variable to reduce space complexities. Here is my attempt.

My basic merge sort logic is as shown below, it consist of two functions:-

1. mergeSort.
2. merge

Their codes are  as shown :-

```
def mergeSort(A, start_index, end_index):
    if ((len(A)) > 1):
        middle = math.floor((start_index + end_index) / 2)
        mergeSort(A[start_index:middle], start_index, middle)
        mergeSort(A[middle:end_index], middle, end_index)
        merge(A[start_index:middle], A[middle: end_index], A)
        #Create a new empty list for array to merge
```

My Merge logic is as shown below :-

```
def merge(U, V, A):   

    m = len(U) - 1
    n = len(V) - 1

    U.append(inf)
    V.append(inf)

    i = j = k = 0

    while(k <= (m + n + 1)):

        if(U[i] < V[j]):
            A[k] = U[i]
            i += 1

        else:
            A[k] = V[j]
            j += 1


        k += 1
```

I have passed A = [5,4,3,2,1] as input to mergeSort. As mergeSort(A, 0, 4), now the output is surprisingly [3,2,5,4,1].

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to comment but you should add in the first function mergeSort of your code

```
If (start_index < end_index) :
```

Comment: It goes into infinite loop.

Comment: @NeelMishra well i code in c++, and there i used to pass the whole array, not the sub-parts, with the if condition i mentioned, it worked for me, it should work for you as well as rest of the code is equivalent to my one in c++. Try implementing that.